# Time Capsule multiple IP addresses

Tags: time-capsule, network

I have two 2TB Time Capsules attached to a network through a Netgear router. Each Time Capsule is connected via Ethernet with the WiFi set to "off".

Each Time Capsule is assigned a unique static IP address; all devices connected to the network are assigned unique static IP addresses.

The Time Capsules randomly add IP addresses. Often the Time Capsule will have the assigned static IP address and two other unique IP addresses. It is truly a random occurrence. Sometimes there is only the assigned static IP address and then one or two additional IP addresses will be discovered to have been taken by the Time Capsule. Sometimes this occurs on only one unit and then it will occur on both. When the random IP address duplicates an assigned IP address for another device on the network, then the inevitable network address conflict error causes problems for the device operation.

I have reset each unit in an attempt to solve the problem, but the random attaching of IP addresses continues.

Comment: I am getting similar behavior with my Meraki gear. Apple capsule keeps claiming same IP address of the Apple TV. Both devices are set with static ip addresses after suspecting dhcp issues but there is no change in behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find the solution:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4890670?tstart=0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.